# Order a table from a related table in Yii2

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a table named `"video"` that does not have `"likes"` in it, because i have created another table `"video-like"` to join each like to the `"user"`.
But i want to sort the videos by likes, and i dont know how to do that.

I am using Yii2 framework and PostgreSQL.

In this example i created a query that is sorted from new to old videos. Thats easy because i dont have to access another table to do it.

```
$this->orderBy(['created_at' => SORT_DESC]);
```

Any help is usefull !

Comment: Please post any code what you tried to implement to achieve the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 nested select.

```
$query = Model()::find();
$subQuery = ModelLikes()::find()
            ->select("COUNT(*) AS amount")
            ->groupBy([
                ModelLikes::tableName() . '.source_id'
            ])
            ->orderBy(['amount' => SORT_DESC]);
$query->leftJoin(['T' => $subQuery],
            Model::tableName() . ".id= T.source_id");
$data = $query->all();
```

you should change model's name and field based on your models.

> source_id is video's id in likes table

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, but I am a little confused by how to implement it, i have never seen dots used in that way... I tried to replace source_id by video_id wich is the video id in viedo_likes table and each "Model" with its respective model. but when i run it it says that video.id does not exist.

Comment: The SQL being executed was: SELECT "video".* FROM "video" LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS "amount" FROM "video_like" GROUP BY "video_like"."video_id" ORDER BY "amount" DESC) "T" ON "video".id= T.video_id

Comment: In yii2, each model has a method with `tableName()` name , so you can use it except of using table's name directly